# python with statement indentation

Tags: python, with-statement

I often have to open files solely to read in the text and do some analysis on the text as in the following example.

```
with open('foo/bar.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
    good_stuff = analyze(text)
```

My question is, does the `good_stuff` line need to be indented? As far as I understand the `with` block exists to automate build up and tear down of some process. If this is all it does then once I have the `text` variable, I'm all good and no longer need to be in the `with` block, correct?

If I have lots of surrounding code, this can lead to large indentation which can be rather annoying. I've tried not indenting and it seems to work, but I've never seen anyone write

```
with open('foo/bar.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
good_stuff = analyze(text)
```

so I'm curious if there is some reason or standard this is done, or maybe I haven't noticed some side effect this causes.

Comment: I suspect that many people prefer the first approach because they're not confident in their understanding of the scoping rules of blocks. They aren't sure whether `text` continues to exist past the end of the `with`, so they take the safe option and only refer to it within that block. This is a rational decision given limited information: if you assume all blocks have their own scope and you're wrong, then your code is four characters longer than it needed to be, but functional. If you assume blocks don't have their own scope and you're wrong, then your code won't work at all.

Comment: @Kevin good point. The former is exactly what I have done as I guess I assumed the block had it's own scope!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second approach is actually better. You should exit the `with` block as soon as you are done with the file. There is no need to keep the file open after you read it.

Answer (score 4):

In this approach:

```
with open('foo/bar.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

good_stuff = analyze(text)
```

You opened the file, read the whole content into a variable called text, you have closed the file and then you analyzed the text.

This is OK, but what if you have get a very big file? In that case I don't think you can go with this approach

```
with open('foo/bar.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
      good_stuff = analyze(line)
```

So this is how I suggest to read your file if you have a big file.

Comment: I like this idea, as some of the files are large. However, what if the things im studying are heavily multi-lined?

Comment: You mean you have got files with very long lines? In case use read(count_of_bytes) to read a portion of that instead of reading line by line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `analyze(text)` with the file open then have it indented or else later is a better .

Answer (score 0):

The with function is used to apply **exit** method on the opened file so that the file will be closed safely. But once you read the content of file to variable "text" there is no rule to keep it indented under "with" block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no need to put `good_stuff` in the indentation block, because after you do `text` it now has a scope in your program like an ordinary object/variable.